# Разные кавычки в прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, прямая-речь

Как правильно?

1. **«„На протяжении веков“ значит „на века“**. Так, по крайней мере, думает мистер кот». – «Нешто вы всё время этому коту-мистеру верите! Он – мошенник 1-й степени, а не мудрец какой-то!»
2. **«„На протяжении веков“ значит «на века»**. Так, по крайней мере, думает мистер кот». – «Нешто вы всё время этому коту-мистеру верите! Он – мошенник 1-й степени, а не мудрец какой-то!»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Об использовании разных кавычек в прямой речи и при цитировании четко сказано в справочнике А. Э. Мильчина и Л. К. Чельцовой:

> **1.** Цитаты заключаются в кавычки такого же рисунка, что и применяемые в осн. тексте в качестве основных.
> **2.** Если внутри цитаты есть слова (словосочетания, фразы), в свою очередь заключенные в кавычки, то последние должны быть другого рисунка, чем кавычки, закрывающие и открывающие цитату (внешние кавычки — обычно елочки **« »**, внутренние — лапки **„ “**).

**„На протяжении веков“ значит «на века»** — такое оформление является ошибочным. Кавычки должны быть одинаковыми. (Значит = означает.)

А с примером, мне кажется, вы перемудрили.
Правильно, думаю, надо писать так:

«"На протяжении веков значит на века" — так, по крайней мере, думает мистер кот». — «Нешто вы всё время этому коту-мистеру верите! Он — мошенник первой степени, а не мудрец какой-то!»

Или так:
— «На протяжении веков значит на века» — так, по крайней мере, думает мистер кот.
— Нешто вы всё время этому коту-мистеру верите! <...>

> **Примечания:** 1. После закрывающих кавычек ставится только тире (независимо от того, каким знаком препинания заканчивается прямая речь) в тех случаях, когда в последующих словах автора содержится характеристика прямой речи, ее оценка и т. д. (авторская ремарка обычно начинается словами: *так говорит, так указывает, вот что сказал, вот как описывает* и т. п.): <...>
> *«Нет ничего прекраснее этих снежных вершин» — так описывает эту местность один путешественник...*

[8.2.4. Рисунок кавычек](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html)
[Прямая речь перед словами автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=157#pp157)

Comment: Как я понимаю, из моих вариантов первый – это правильный. Так?

Comment: Кавычки в первом варианте ("на протяжении веков" и "на века") не нужны. Но если бы были необходимы, то одинаковые.